# How to use generic for code reusability

Tags: c#

I want to use Generic for reusability.

Code to be applied are listed below.

```
pubic Class Test < T >
{

    T item;

    ...

    public void set(T item)
    {
          this.item = item;

          // if (T type == int) {...}

          // if (T type == string) {...}

          abc();
    }

    private void abc()
    {
          ...
    }
}
```

Question1. I heard that using attribute is best solution in this situation.
           How do I implement this? Please, Tell me if you have any example.
(Type will be added continually)

Question2. Is using Generic best solution about above example??

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don´t understand your question. Why do you want to set an attribute? Do you have any use-scenario for which this method is used?

Comment: Having conditionals like `if (x is string) { ... }` inside of generic classes is always a bad sign. If you need to treat different types differently, use different classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid checking for particular types inside generic methods and classes. You could make `set` a template method and then override the type-specific behaviour inside subclasses which specify the type `T` e.g.

```
public class Test<T> {
    public void Set(T item) {
        this.item = item;
        this.OnSet(item);
        abc();
    }
    protected virtual void OnSet(T item) { }
}

public class IntTest : Test<int> {
    protected override void OnSet(int item) { ... }
}

public class StringTest : Test<string> { 
    protected override void OnSet(string item) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

if (item is int) else if(item is string)...

Whether it's the best approach or not, I leave up to others.